# Floating div not in expected location when positioned using CSS left & top with absolute positioning

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a floating tooltip div (programmatically appended to the body node) that should be appearing at say [100, 150] on the document, and to achieve this I setting the following css via jQuery:

```
var tooltip = //my tooltip element wrapped in jQuery object
var targetLeft = 100; //Calculated
var targetTop = 150; //Calculated

tooltip.css({left: targetLeft, top: targetTop, display: '', opacity: 1.0});
```

The abolute position is inherited from an external stylesheet:

```
.tooltip {
    border-color: none;
    width: 310px;
    margin: 4em;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    z-index:9999;
    position:absolute;
}
```

This is working nicely except the tooltip is appearing 60-80 pixels lower than it should be. So even though the CSS theoretically sets the position to [100, 150], it in fact appears at [100, ~210].

As far as I can see I am assigning the correct coordinates in the CSS, and from my understanding of absolute positioning the coordinates are relative to the document, so nothing should be offsetting the tooltip when it displays. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

This occurs consistently accross I.E. 6, Firefox 10 and Chrome 14 on Windows.

Has anyone experienced (and solved) a similar issue? It is being a real pain, and becuase the vertical offset is not quite consitent a 'magic number' to fix the position is not a feasible option.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide a demo of the code, or even just the code? and a screenshot as well? we can't determine what causes this by just describing it. let the code speak for itself

Comment: is that typo in your code? you should use px on top and left - left:100px; top:150px;

Comment: @andreas the OP said the css is applied in jQuery (probably using `.css()` but we can't tell), which assumes `px` if no units are specified.

Comment: @ert if you are doing that via jquery `.css()`, you don't need pixels. In any case, could you show some markup and more javascript?

Comment: I tried using tooltip.css({left: myleft + 'px', top: myTop + 'px'}) but as discussed, no change was visible.
I will post the real that sets the css soon.

Comment: The code that sets the css is here:
    helpElem.css({left: targetLeft, top: targetTop, display: '', opacity: 1.0});
Where targetLeft and targetTop are numeric values.
The abolsute positioning is being inherited from an external stylesheet:
.tooltip {
    border-color: none;
    width: 310px;
    margin: 4em;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    z-index:9999;
    position:absolute;
}

Comment: Provide the code dude, we dont what is your structure and on which elements your applying your script and css may some other element is giving u trouble..

Answer (score 0):

if your position: absolute element is within other statically positioned elements, then they will change its fundamental offsets.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @virmaior however this element is being inserted at the end of the document's body node.
I am assuming that by using the body node as the parent I can avoid inheriting offsets from any other elements.